# Google Sheets Webhooks stopped working after 1 week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, webhooks

I created webhooks that fire when an order (or subscription change) is done in my woocommerce store. I made that work and have a table of all test changes. 
Big question now is that all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore, although it worked last week when I set everything up (and didnt change anything till then).
Additional info: I always let every webhook from woocommerce not only go to the specific google sheets link, but also to a testing environment (in my case to webhook.site), where I always received all webhooks. I take this as a sign that the issue is not coming from woocommerce.
(And yes, I have checked several times that the links to the google Sheets are correct. They even worked flawlessly a week ago)

I pasted all the code used below, whereas most of the code is just to extract variable values.

Do you need more insights in order to help?

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request

function doPost(e) {
  var myData             = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_number       = myData.number; 
  var order_status       = myData.status; 
  var order_created      = myData.date_created; 

  var order_modified     = myData.date_modified; 
  var date_paid          = myData.date_paid; 
  var customer_id        = myData.customer_id; 
  var discount_total     = myData.discount_total; 
  var discount_tax       = myData.discount_tax; 
  var shipping_total     = myData.shipping_total; 
  var shipping_tax       = myData.shipping_tax; 
  var total              = myData.total; 

  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name; 
  var billing_last_name  = myData.billing.last_name; 
  var billing_company    = myData.billing.company; 
  var billing_address    = myData.billing.address_1; 
  var billing_city       = myData.billing.city; 
  var billing_postcode   = myData.billing.postcode; 
  var billing_email      = myData.billing.email; 
  var billing_phone      = myData.billing.phone; 

  var shipping_first_name = myData.shipping.first_name; 
  var shipping_last_name  = myData.shipping.last_name; 
  var shipping_company    = myData.shipping.company; 
  var shipping_address    = myData.shipping.address_1; 
  var shipping_city       = myData.shipping.city; 
  var shipping_postcode   = myData.shipping.postcode; 

  var ernaehrungsstil    = myData.line_items[0].meta[0].value; 
  var mahlzeiten_woche   = myData.line_items[0].meta[1].value; 
  var discount_code      = myData.coupon_lines[0].code; 

  var product_name       = myData.line_items[0].name; 
  var product_qty        = myData.line_items[0].quantity; 
  var product_total      = myData.line_items[0].total; 
  var product_total_tax  = myData.line_items[0].total_tax; 
  var payment_method     = myData.payment_method_title; 
  var shipping_method    = myData.shipping_lines[0].method_title; 

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp,order_created,order_modified,date_paid,order_number,customer_id,order_status,product_name,product_qty,ernaehrungsstil,mahlzeiten_woche,payment_method,total,product_total,product_total_tax,discount_total,discount_tax,discount_code,shipping_total,shipping_tax,shipping_method,billing_first_name,billing_last_name,billing_company,billing_address,billing_city,billing_postcode,billing_email,billing_phone,shipping_first_name,shipping_last_name,shipping_company,shipping_address,shipping_city,shipping_postcode]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details like the runtime environment that your project is using ( V8 or Rhino) and the errors logged in the execution transcript or in the project executions page.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with your code so I would guess it might be a V8/Rhino issue.  There are several upload issue on the issue tracker so try switching back to Rhino.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I checked on runtime environment. It was v8, but after reading that v8 just got introduced a couple of weeks ago I disabled it and went for the legacy one, tried again but no result. Checking both the execution transcript and the project execution page was very strange, as it showed no executions or insights (although 2nd of March it was achieving the desired results). Anything else it could be?

Comment: Hey Cooper. Thanks for checking the code. I just tried it after switching back to Rhino (which is just named legacy now). I get no results after the switch, as I did when I wrote this question. I feel confused tho as it worked before.

Comment: Are you getting an error on the logs? Are the executions displaying in the "executions" panel (View -> executions)?